# Grails Oauth2 and Spring Security Core - Wrong principal

Tags: spring, grails, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, principal

I'm implementing google login to my Grails 3.1.9 application with the help of Spring Security Oauth2 plugin.

I'm stuck at problem with creating principal for authenticated user.

After user logs in via google, there is associated token to  `SecurityContextHolder.context` with principal as shown below:

[image: wrong principal format]

This is causing problems with rendering views which work with other user details not included.

After user logs in normally using spring security, the created principal looks like this:

[image: right principal format]

Used plugins:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2:1.1.0'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-google:1.1.0'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
```

And repositories:

https://github.com/MatrixCrawler/grails-spring-security-oauth2

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core

Does someone know how to deal with this problem? I can include some parts of my code if needed. I'll be really glad for any help because I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) please add a bit of your code to your question. That should make it easier for people to find what could be the possible issues.

Comment: You might need to implement your own user details class in order to store extra properties in the user details.